# Other users cannot view content published to front page

Tags: views

why can't other users view content posted by user? Where can I find this permission issue?

Comment: It all depends on what have you done to your permissions - what have you clicked in GUI, what modules you have installed, possibly also what caching options you're using, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin/people/permissions and ensure that "View published content" under the title "Node" is selected.

Also, if using [OG](https://drupal.org/project/OG) go to admin/config/group/context and ensure that "Node" is enabled, and that if you have "Content" under admin/config/group/permissions that these permissions are also correctly selected.

Also ensure that the node you want all users to see has the two checkboxes *Published* and *Promoted to front page* checkbox ticked. You find these under "Publishing options" when you edit the node as the administrator.

The defaults for these are set per content type. If a user that is *not* the administrator is creating content, these must be set by default for the type. The built-in content type "Article" has these checked by default, so the user should create article of type "Article" (or another type that has these two boxes checked by default) for the article to be visible on the front page for non-admin users.

Comment: Also, as a second thought, ensure that the user who is saving the new content is also Publishing it, and that it is a content type that is allowed to display on the front page!

Comment: Even if view published content is checked and the user who posted it promotes it to front page still the other user cannot view his post

Comment: Can user 1 (Administrator) see the content, and can the user who posted the content see it on the front page?

Comment: only the admin can view his post but i want it that also other users can view admin post

Comment: OK, please clarify, are you using the OG module, and is the Admin able to see it on the Front Page, or through the content list?

Comment: I am not using the OG module just views

Comment: OK then, please expand your question to include the information you have given me, and also anything else you deem to be relevant that would help someone help you to solve this issue. Please also include some more information in your question as to what you have done to attempt to solve this issue yourself, and perhaps some screenshots of your settings.

Please help us to help you!

Comment: When I log in to my user account (not the admin )I can view the tab but when I click that tab I cannot view my content which admin has posted.

Comment: I have a node access module and I have checked that other users can view the post of a user

Comment: Solved. Thanks for all your replies.I have a node access module. I went to configure and I went into my content type which I want other users to see and I have checked the "View" to other user listed so that other users can view the post of a administrator/author